# FFImageLoading is throwing exception in Android with error: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load list of method overrides due to Method not found:

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I just started using FFImageLoading for a Xamarin cross platform project and the Android MainActivity.cs file is throwing an unhandled exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load list of method overrides due
>   to Method not found:void
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.add_LayoutChange(System.EventHandler`1)

I've looked at this a lot already and don't understand what exactly to do here. Here are the versions I'm working with:

- Xamarin.Forms v3.6.0.264807
- Xamarin.FFImageLoading v2.4.4.859
- Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms v2.4.4.859

I understand that the versions must be correct to fix this problem.

I would put more but I don't have hours and hours to figure out how to use this website correctly. I keep getting errors about how my code isn't idented 4 spaces (when it obviously was!!!!!!!!!!!!!). I'm just trying to get this question out there successfully.

Comment: I filled out all boxes correctly! I know because I took the time out to make sure! I wonder why it looks like ******* above!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update

This issue has been resolved in release version 2.4.6.929.  If you're experiencing this error then please update Xamarin Forms and FFImageLoading.

---

### Original Answer

There is an issue with the version of FFImageLoading you're using (v2.4.4.859) and Xamarin Forms version 3.6 (well, versions 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6).

You can view the issue on their github [Init exception with latest Xamarin.Forms 3.4 / 3.6](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/1154).  There is a fix in the pre-release version of FFImageLoading (v2.4.5.870-pre).

The only fixes that I know of at the moment are:

1. Downgrade FFImageLoading to the previous version (2.4.3.840)
2. Downgrade Xamarin Forms
3. Use the pre-release version FFImageLoading (v2.4.5.870-pre, or v2.4.5.880-pre see update)

Be aware that the pre-release version of any software may be unstable and may still be in development.  **I would not recommend using pre-releases in a production environment.**

---

### Update

A user (PureWeen) has posted on the [issues](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/1154) page:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/2.4.4.859
>
> - is incompatible with the latest versions of 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6, 4.0 pre(*)
>
> ---
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/2.4.4.859
>   and all 2.4.5 versions prior to
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/2.4.5.880-pre
>   are compatible with:
>
> - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/3.6.0.220655
> - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/3.5.0.169047
> - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/3.4.0.1029999
>
> ---
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/2.4.5.880-pre
>
> - is compatible with the latest versions of 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6
>
> ---
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/2.4.5.870-pre
>
> - is compatible with XF 3.6.0.264807

---

You can get the pre-release version from NuGet by selecting the `Include prerelease` checkbox in VisualStudio:

[image]

Comment: Yal, the pre-release version fixed the problem, thanks so much!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a solution and and update. A quick search landed me here and a few clicks later, things are working again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix it with this following code meanwhile.

--MainActivity.cs--

```
 var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => true;

            var client = new HttpClient(handler);
            ImageService.Instance.Initialize(new Configuration
            {
                HttpClient = client
            });
```